# How do I count the number of even digits in a number?

Tags: regex, perl

I have phone numbers in the following format:

```
$number = '06-20-459-3698';
```

I need to count the number of those phone numbers that have AT LEAST 5 even digits in them.

I think I can do it with a regexp like `/.*[.*[02468]]{5}.*/`, but how do I include two different lists of items in one [] pair?

I am using perl.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[.*[02468]]{5}` doesn't make sense: The regex engine will parse `[.*[02468]` as a character class: match either a dot, asterisk, opening square bracket or `02468`, folowed by `]` 5 times

Comment: You mean even digits. The number 3465 has 2 even digits.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, I've tried to share my way of thinking with that.
I need a regex that accepts (anything zero or more times followed by an even number) 5 times.

Comment: @xanyi Try something like this [`^(?:.*?[02468]){5,}.*$`](http://regex101.com/r/tU9jG7)

Comment: @HamZa That did the trick, thanks.
Why do that work, what does the , mean in the {}?

Comment: @xanyi `^` means begin of string, `$` means end of string. `(?:)` is a non capturing group. `{5,}` means repeat the non-capturing group 5 or more times. `.*?` will match anything ungreedy, `[02468]` will match an even number. So basically it will match anything ungreedy until if finds an even number. It will do this at least 5 times. We've got `.*` at the end to match the rest of the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the transliteration as shown in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop#tr%2fSEARCHLIST%2fREPLACEMENTLIST%2fcdsr):

```
print $number if $number =~ tr/24680// >= 5;
```

Comment: perhaps braces before >=5

Comment: @mpapec: Not needed. Try with `-MO=Deparse,-p`.

Answer (score 2):

To find the count of how many even numbers are in the string, you could do something like this.

```
my $number = '06-20-459-3698';
my $count  = () = $number =~ /[02468]/g; 
print $number if $count >= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to HamZa the following did trick:

```
 /(.*[02468]){5}/
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to maintain this, especially when simpler and idiomatic solutions exist.

Comment: What @choroba said, take a look at the other solutions. They are more readable and better maintainable.